# Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute error on running

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am wondering why my program is running this error every time I get to this stage? All it is doing is getting records from a database and displaying them on a combobox?

I get two errors:

> Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute.

and

> Syntax error (comma) in query expression '(Forename , Surname <> 'Mr').

Code attached below:

```
        Try
            'Get REGISTRATION classes
            Dim RD As OleDbDataReader
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DATA.accdb")
            Dim commStr As String = "Select Registration from students WHERE (Registration <> '"
            Dim comm As OleDbCommand

            con.Open()
            If step4regcombobox.Items.Count = 0 Then
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Registration from students", con)
                RD = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While RD.Read
                    step4regcombobox.Items.Add(RD.GetString(0))
                End While
            End If
            For Each i As Object In step4regcombobox.Items
                comm = New OleDbCommand(commStr & i & "')", con)
                RD = comm.ExecuteReader
                While RD.Read
                    step4regcombobox.Items.Add(RD.GetString(0))
                    Exit While
                End While
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failure to return classes on Step 4." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Try
            'Get TEACHERS
            Dim RD2 As OleDbDataReader
            Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DATA.accdb")
            Dim commStr2 As String = "Select Title , Forename , Surname from teachers WHERE (Forename , Surname <> '"
            Dim comm2 As OleDbCommand
            con2.Open()
            If step4teachercombobox.Items.Count = 0 Then
                Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("Select Title , Forename , Surname from teachers", con2)
                RD2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
                While RD2.Read
                    step4teachercombobox.Items.Add(RD2.GetString(0))
                End While
            End If
            For Each i2 As Object In step4teachercombobox.Items
                comm2 = New OleDbCommand(commStr2 & i2 & "')", con2)
                RD2 = comm2.ExecuteReader
                While RD2.Read
                    step4teachercombobox.Items.Add(RD2.GetString(0))
                    Exit While
                End While
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failure to return teachers on Step 4." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
        End Try
        step4.Visible = True
```

Comment: You didnt bother to tell us where the collection error happens, so I will guess it inside the `For Each i2 As Object In step4teachercombobox.Items` block.  Inside that block you are adding to the items collection which you cant do - you cannot iterate a collection and modify it at the same time.  There is no need for any of that - bind a DataTable to the CBOs.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]; 1 question per post please with compleat information

Comment: The second error should be pretty clear - the query `WHERE (Forename , Surname <> '` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your app is also leaking resources and those error messages in the catch blocks are not helping you.  See also [Remove Items from Collection in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20176182/1070452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop here:

```
        For Each i As Object In step4regcombobox.Items
            comm = New OleDbCommand(commStr & i & "')", con)
            RD = comm.ExecuteReader
            While RD.Read
                step4regcombobox.Items.Add(RD.GetString(0))
                Exit While
            End While
        Next
```

You are modifying `step4regcombobox.Items` while you are iterating over it.  This is not allowed.

The loop itself looks highly suspicious: why would later items in the list be derived from earlier items?

Assuming the logic is correct, you will have to refactor the `For Each` loop to perform the `Add` outside.

e.g.

```
Dim itemsToAdd As New List(Of String)

'Then, replace the addition to the combo item list with this:
itemsToAdd.Add(RD.GetString(0))

'Then, after the loop is complete:
step4regcombobox.Items.AddRange(itemsToAdd)
```

(I'm assuming that step4regcombobox.Items implements `AddRange`, if it does not, you may have to loop over `itemsToAdd` manually and add each one in turn.)

Comment: This helped me! Thank you.