# Visual Basic reduce the number of iterations in a for loop?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to cycle through a listbox, removing an item where it doesn't meet the required conditions. Would it be possible to reduce the number of iterations while currently in the for loop? I've tried reducing the maximum variable while in the loop but that doesn't appear to be working. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
For x = 0 To total - 1
     If lstOut.Items.Item(x).substring(11, 10) <> studentField.sName Then
             lstOut.Items.RemoveAt(x)
             total = total - 1
     End If
Next
```

Comment: You should avoid modifying a list while iterating through it. This said, once you remove the item at position x, it means that the next item has the same index than you currently have. You can do `x -= 1` to prevent skipping over it, but it's rather a lame way to proceed. I suggest using the loop to create a new list of items which you can attribute to the control after the loop.

Comment: I think you'd be better of using a `while` loop in this case

Comment: agree wthe @laancelot... you definately don't want to be manipulating the list while going through it like that... i'm guessing that you're experiencing an error when you get to the end. The preferred way to go about it is in reverse. Start at the end of the list and work your way to the front: 
` for x = total -1 to 0 step -1 `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Items from Collection in a loop (Combo Box items)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176130/remove-items-from-collection-in-a-loop-combo-box-items)

Answer (score 1):

In order to **resolve that** you can start from the **last element** and go in down direction (like the code below shows)
without take care to removing iterations

```
For x = lstOut.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If lstOut.Items.Item(x).substring(11, 10) <> studentField.sName Then
        lstOut.Items.RemoveAt(x)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: However, I see now that is said before even from @TechGnome in comments above

Comment: I still read more accurately the next. I prefer to give more importance to a good solution also give credits to author. Thank you :)